# React-bootstrap navbar collapse issue

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I'm having this issue, seems to have something to do with js or popper, I don't know... After toggling, the bar is not formatted correctly. Here's the issue:

[image: After toggle]

Here's the code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Nav, Navbar } from "react-bootstrap";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { Badge, IconButton, Menu, MenuItem } from "@material-ui/core";
import { createMuiTheme, MuiThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import PersonIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Person";
import {
  openLoginTab,
  openEditProfileTab,
  openEditPasswordTab
} from "../../utils/auth";

    const NavBar = ({ token }) => {   const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = useState(null);   const handleClick = (event) => {
        setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);   };   const handleClose = () => {
        setAnchorEl(null);   };   const theme = createMuiTheme({
        palette: {
          primary: {
            main: "#70CBB0"
          }
        }   });   const iconsColor = "white";   return (
        <Navbar bg="dark" fixed="top" expand="md" variant="dark" collapseOnSelect>
          <Navbar.Brand href="/homepage" to="/homepage" as={Link}>
            H
          </Navbar.Brand>
          <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="lotto-navbar-collapse" />
          <Navbar.Collapse id="lotto-navbar-collapse">
            <Nav className="ml-auto d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
              <Nav.Link href="/games" to="/games" as={Link}>
                games
              </Nav.Link>
              <Nav.Link href="/shop" to="/shop" as={Link}>
                shop
              </Nav.Link>
              <Nav.Link href="/products" to="/products" as={Link}>
                products
              </Nav.Link>
              <div className="nav-item">
                <IconButton onClick={handleClick}>
                  <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                    <Badge
                      color={token ? "primary" : "secondary"}
                      variant="dot"
                      anchorOrigin={{
                        vertical: "top",
                        horizontal: "right"
                      }}
                    >
                      <PersonIcon
                        color="action"
                        aria-controls="user-menu"
                        aria-haspopup="true"
                        style={{ color: iconsColor }}
                      />
                    </Badge>
                  </MuiThemeProvider>
                </IconButton>
              </div>
              <Menu
                id="user-menu"
                anchorEl={anchorEl}
                keepMounted
                open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
                onClose={handleClose}
              >
                {!token && (
                  <MenuItem
                    onClick={() => {
                      handleClose();
                      openLoginTab();
                    }}
                  >
                    <Nav.Link href="#" style={{ color: "black", padding: 0 }}>
                      Login
                    </Nav.Link>
                  </MenuItem>
                )}
                {token && (
                  <MenuItem
                    onClick={() => {
                      handleClose();
                      openEditPasswordTab();
                    }}
                  >
                    <Nav.Link href="#" style={{ color: "black", padding: 0 }}>
                      Edit password
                    </Nav.Link>
                  </MenuItem>
                )}
                {token && (
                  <MenuItem
                    onClick={() => {
                      handleClose();
                      openEditProfileTab();
                    }}
                  >
                    <Nav.Link href="#" style={{ color: "black", padding: 0 }}>
                      Edit profile
                    </Nav.Link>
                  </MenuItem>
                )}
                {token && (
                  <MenuItem
                    onClick={() => {
                      handleClose();
                      sessionStorage.clear();
                      window.history.pushState({}, "homepage", "/homepage");
                      window.location.reload();
                    }}
                  >
                    <Nav.Link href="#" style={{ color: "black", padding: 0 }}>
                      Logout
                    </Nav.Link>
                  </MenuItem>
                )}
              </Menu>
            </Nav>
          </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Navbar>   ); };
    
    export default NavBar;
```

I'm using:

- "bootstrap": "^4.6.0"
- "react-bootstrap": "^1.5.2";
- "jquery": "^3.6.0"
- "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.3"
- "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2"

Hope you anyone can help :)

Answer (score 0):

Solved it in navbar.scss. Before:

```
nav {
heigth: 80px };
```

If you define the height, it gets unformatted. If you want to define height, set it through padding :)